# How to use bash plugin in Intellij with windows

Tags: shell, intellij-idea

How to use Intellij bash plugin in windows? I see below error while running sample shell script.

```
Error running 'sample_shell.sh': Executable is not specified
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to have shell to run such script.
For example take [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win), it comes with great bash shell.

Then in Intellij settings set Shell path to where Git bash.exe is installed.
All new Terminal windows in Intellij from now on will be in bash shell.

[image: Terminal shell settings]